# Python Binary Tree

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I'm working on a binary tree in Python3 and so far almost everything has been working like expected; however, I have a function that is supposed to return a list of all children for any given node and for whatever reason I'm only getting a list of the object addresses, and not calling my overridden `__str__(self)` method.

```
from collections import deque  # http://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html

class BinaryNode:  # binary tree functionality via iterative means

    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.Left = None
        self.Right = None
        self.Parent = None
        self.Name = name
        self.Data = data
        return

    def AddNew(self, name, data):
        q = []
        q.append(self)
        while q:
            i = q.pop()
            if i.Name == name:
                i.Data = data
                return i
            elif name < i.Name:
                if i.Left:
                    q.append(i.Left)
                else:
                    i.Left = BinaryNode(name, data)
                    i.Left.Parent = i
                    return i.Left
            else:
                if i.Right:
                    q.append(i.Right)
                else:
                    i.Right = BinaryNode(name, data)
                    i.Right.Parent = i
                    return i.Right

    def Find(self, name):
        q = deque()
        q.append(self)
        '''if self.Left: q.append(self.Left)
        if self.Right: q.append(self.Right)'''
        while q:
            i = q.pop()
            print(i)
            if i.Name == name:
                return i
            elif name < i.Name:
                if i.Left: q.append(i.Left)
                else: return None
            else:
                if i.Right: q.append(i.Left)
                else: return None

    def Children(self):
        children = []
        q = deque()
        if self.Left: q.append(self.Left)
        if self.Right: q.append(self.Right)
        while q:
            i = q.popleft()
            if i.Left: q.append(i.Left)
            if i.Right: q.append(i.Right)
            children.append(i)
        return children

    def Parents(self):
        lst = []
        i = self.Parent
        while i is not None:
            lst.append(i)
            i = i.Parent
        return lst

    def __str__(self): return "{} : {}".format(self.Name, self.Data)
```

and I'm testing it by calling

```
test = BinaryNode("Jesse", 21)
print(test)
print(test.AddNew("David", 22))
print(test.AddNew("Marli", 23))
print(str(test.Children()))
print(test.Find("David"))
print(test.Find("David").Children())
print(test.Find("Gary")) #Will return None
```

with the resulting console output

```
Jesse : 21
David : 22
Marli : 23
[<__main__.BinaryNode object at 0x000000000333E160>, <__main__.BinaryNode object at 0x000000000333E1D0>, <__main__.BinaryNode object at 0x000000000333E198>]
David : 22
[<__main__.BinaryNode object at 0x000000000333E1D0>]
None
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the answer I implemented:

```
def __repr__ (self): return str(self)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python containers always use the *representation* of contained objects.

Implement a `__repr__` method too and that'll be used when printing the list; you can make it an alias for `__str__` if you wish:

```
 __repr__ = __str__
```

or explicitly print each element in your list:

```
print(', '.join(map(str, test.Children())))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Definitely didn't know about that. Here's what I ended up doing `def __repr__ (self): return str(self)`

Comment: On an unrelated note people should be wary, I think I need to redo my `AddNew` method.